# Different nth-child properties in different media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, css-selectors

i'm working with responsive design and in my css there are e.g. three different media queries with a list item style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1350px) {
    li.item:nth-child(n+6) {
        border-top: 1px solid #d9ddd3;
    }
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1550px) {
    li.item:nth-child(n+7) {
        border-top: 1px solid #d9ddd3;
    }
    h1 {
        color: green;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1750px) {
    li.item:nth-child(n+8) {
        border-top: 1px solid #d9ddd3;
    }
    h1 {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

So beginning with the 6th/7th/8th li item, i'm adding a top border. The problem is:

- For 1350px i got n+6
- For 1550px i got n+6
- For 1750px i got n+6

When i add another earlier nth-child property, this earlier one is set for every coming nth-child for this li item.

I added for testing some more other styles, like green, blue and red headline and these styles are working.

What's the problem?

with best regards
Sebastian

**=> Solution**

Okay got it now with reseting previos nth-child properties like this:

```
li.item:nth-child(n+7) {
    border-top: 0;
}
li.item:nth-child(n+8) {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9ddd3;
}
```

Comment: If you answer your own question you should post the answer as an answer

Answer (score 5):

You are only checking for minimum values, not maximums, therefore overlap occurs. *(Your question was a little unclear, that is the problem no?)* If my understanding of media queries is correct, you have no rules there that should cascade over and replace the existing rules, as I assume you intended.

Try the following conditions instead:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1350px) and (max-width : 1549px)
@media only screen and (min-width : 1550px) and (max-width : 1749px)
@media only screen and (min-width : 1750px)
```